# Angular 2 and Angular 4 difference in base code

Tags: angular

I have one code base (created with `ng new my-project-name`) how to identify that code is Angular 2 or 4?
I have tried googling but couldn't find anything

Comment: check the package.json file or run `npm outdated` which will tell you

Answer (score 0):

Go to your package.json file if your dependencies look for dependencies that start with "@angular/..." if it starts with 2. something is version 2 if it starts with 4.something it is version 4.

Comment: however, if it uses `^2...` then it might have been updated to angular 4 so running npm outdated is the better option